# Select lower case column with group by or select lower(column) in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

How to achieve following in rails 4?

Here is my PostgreSQL query and works correctly

```
SELECT lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc FROM categories  GROUP BY c_name  ORDER BY cc desc LIMIT 3
```

Ii gives me following results

```
 "ecommerce solutions";6
 "vmware";6
 "big data analytics";5
```

But when I write same query in Rails 4 as

```
Category.select("lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc").group("c_name").order("cc desc").limit(3)
```

Above query generates following query which is same as above PostgreSQL query

```
SELECT lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc FROM "categories"  GROUP BY c_name  ORDER BY cc desc LIMIT 3
```

gives following results

```
[#<Category id: nil>, #<Category id: nil>, #<Category id: nil>]
```

Why this is happening ? when I cut my query to

```
 Category.select("lower(name)").limit(3)
```

This also does not work, and results into

```
 [#<Category id: nil>, #<Category id: nil>, #<Category id: nil>]
```

I want to do group on `lower(name)` with count as aggregation, I have many variances of `name` in `Category` model

Ex. data set

```
"Vmware" and "VMware" and "VMWARE" and "vmware"
```

How can I group on lower(name) in Rails 4?

In simple words, How to write equivalent query of following in Rails 4?

```
SELECT lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc FROM categories  GROUP BY c_name  ORDER BY cc desc LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Have you tried this : `Category.select("lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc").group("lower(name)").order("cc desc").limit(3)`

Comment: @AmitThawait Yes I tried, No luck

Comment: I think you might be gettig the correct result but it is not showing in the result since c_name & cc are the actual attributes and u have not selected id in the select clause. Try iterating the result set and check c_name and cc for each result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is correct, but Rails displays it wrong. Just access results manually:

```
results = Category.select("lower(name) as c_name, count(*) as cc").group("c_name").order("cc desc").limit(3) 
results.first['c_name']
```